# Sound redirected to speaker output

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, speakers, headphone-jack

I have a Toshiba Satellite L755 - 180 laptop with Win7 64-bit. The problem is that when Skype is open (especially during a call) and I start playing a Youtube video all sound is redirected to the headphones output (nothing comes out from the speakers, incoming voice is also blocked). The "Do nothing" solution in the communications tab does not work,  the headphones do not appear in the playback devices list or the volume mixer drop down menu and therefore I can not change the default device.

So how can I stop the sound from being rerouted to the headphones output and come out through the speakers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Judging by your attempt to reply to your answer with a commen you should use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) to have your accounts merged. You'll then be able to comment on and edit this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem with a different model laptop. The solution that worked for me was to Uninstall skype, clean the registry (I used CCleaner), and reinstall skype.